# Is it possible to route traffic based on source address or VLAN?

Tags: cisco, routing

I currently have two Cisco Cat5505s as the core switches in my network (layer 2 and 3), and we're looking to move over to a new WAN infrastructure, and subsequently re-IP address everything.

At the moment, anything from *new IP address range* to *remote legacy IP* attempts to route over the legacy WAN, and is subsequently lost, so I need to route it via the new WAN router whilst keeping the *legacy IP address range* working as is. All routes are currently defined statically.

Is there any way I can get my traffic to route to the same end point by different routes depending on which source IP, or VLAN the traffic originates from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use route mapping, however the specifics at the moment are eluding me.  Look into the command, were you planning to do this all with the switches or specifically with routers??  You can route pretty much based on any policy with route maps.

Comment: As I manage the switches, but not the routers, I was hoping to do it all using the RSM of the switches.